# Clustering or multiple correspondence analysis for a set of check-all-that-apply questions in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, correspondence-analysis

I have a dataset that contains a set of check-all-that-apply questions. Let's say it goes like this

Q1. "Which sports do you play"

- A. Football B. Basketball C. ... etc. etc. etc.

Q2. "Which of the following elements motivated you to play sports?"

- A. Competitiveness B. Achievement C. ... etc. etc. etc.

There are 4 goals I want to achieve:

1. Understand which sports are "close" to each other
2. Understand which elements are "close" to each other
3. Understand which sports are associated with which elements
4. Categorize participants considering their participation preferences in sports (e.g. stamina sports players vs. agility
   sports player vs. etc.)

Is it valid to do K-means clustering on a table like this (note: the actual data is much larger; this table is only for demo)? Why and why not?

Is multiple correspondence analysis a better way? Why and why not?

```
football <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
basketball <- c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1)
other <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
df<- data.frame(football, basketball, other)
m = as.matrix(df)
t(m) %*% m / colSums(m)

#             football basketball     other
# football   1.0000000        0.5 0.2500000
# basketball 0.6666667        1.0 0.3333333
# other      1.0000000        1.0 1.0000000
```

Comment: Hey Yukilia, 
I have not read a lot about correspondence-analysis, so I will only speak to k-means. your data is not set up in the proper format for running a k-means clustering analysis. Every row should be an observation and every column a variable.  Here is a link to a stack Exchange that may give some help with your question. [what data structure to use for my cluster analysis] (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81539/what-data-structure-to-use-for-my-cluster-analysis-or-what-cluster-analysis-to-u) Hope this helps.

Comment: multiple correspondance analysis is a method for transforming your categorical variables into a continuous form, for downstream clustering etc. It does this, like what you have done, making binary dummy variables from categorical ones. For example sports will become 01 with football, basketball etc

Comment: So with what you now, it's ok to do k-means, but you can also consider hierachical clustering (hclust) with the Jaccard index for distance matrix, e.g dist(MATRIX,method="binary")